# Asymptotic relations of $x$ and $x/(\log\log x)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

This problem is from Problem in Analytic Number theory by M.Ram Murty (Page no. 128).\

$\pi(x,z) = \# (n \leq x: n \ \text{is not divisible by any prime} \ p < z)$

We have, $\pi(x,z) \ll \frac{x}{\log z} +O(2^z).$

One can write $\pi(x) \leq \pi(x,z) + z$, where $\pi(x)=$ number of prime upto $x$.

Choose $z= \log x$, prove that $\pi(x)= O\bigg(\frac{x}{\log \log x}\bigg)$.

After plugging $z= \log x$, I got $\pi(x)= \frac{x}{\log \log x} + x^{\log 2} + \log x$

I used the fact that $ x^{\log y}= y^ {\log x}$ in intermediate step.
Also, consider base of the logrithmic is e.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2720686/edit) your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts

Comment: Will you provide the definition of $\pi(x,z)$ in your post?

Comment: What have you tried so far? In particular, what happens when you plug $z$ into the formulas that you already have?